# Выбор файлов в QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть QComboBox, который показывает, какие папки я могу выбрать.

```
QDir path("/home/dev/test-project/");
QStringList files = path.entryList(QDir::Dirs);
ui->cB_Karte->addItems(files);
```

Что я хочу сделать, чтобы после нажатия на папку в `QComboBox`, в `QTreeView` отображались доступные там `.tiff` файлы. После выбора файла, присвоение полного пути к переменной:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `class MainWidget`

```
QFileSystemModel *model;
```

В конструктор

```
model = new QFileSystemModel();
model->setNameFilters(QStringList()<<"*.tiff");
model->setNameFilterDisables(false);
ui->treeView->setModel(model);
```

В обработчик бокса

```
ui->treeView->setRootIndex(model->index(ui->comboBox->currentText()));
```

Событие `on_treeView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)`

```
path = model->filePath(index);
```

Comment: что в вашем случае model? ибо у меня показывает,‘model’ was not declared in this scope
     model = new QFileSystemModel();
     ^

Comment: @Insider, сохраните model в поле вашего класса, чтобы модель была доступна в любом его методе